# What is the difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

Both these joins will give me the same results:

```
SELECT * FROM table JOIN otherTable ON table.ID = otherTable.FK
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN otherTable ON table.ID = otherTable.FK
```

Is there any difference between the statements in performance or otherwise?

Does it differ between different **SQL** implementations?

Comment: per the ANSI SQL 92 specification, they are identical: "3) If a <qualified join> is specified and a <join type> is not specified, then INNER is implicit."

Answer (score 1568, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent, but `INNER JOIN` can be a bit clearer to read, especially if the query has other join types (i.e. `LEFT` or `RIGHT` or `CROSS`) included in it.

Comment: Is this true for all data bases (e.g. SQL, postgres?) Does anyone know a link to the documentation explaining this?

Comment: It's ANSI SQL standard. See more: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92

Comment: @Ivanzinho: Keyboard strokes are not the measure of query or program complexity. Real life complexity comes from maintainability, where readability plays a major role. The fact that when it says INNER JOIN, you can be sure of what it does and that it's supposed to be just that, whereas a plain JOIN will leave you, or someone else, wondering what the standard said about the implementation and was the INNER/OUTER/LEFT left out by accident or by purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Indian for your links. The _key_ holds in page 181 of the first one, when describing the generative grammar of page 180: "If a <qualified join> is specified and a <join type> is not specified, then INNER is implicit."

Answer (score 355):

No, there is no difference, pure [**syntactic sugar**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_sugar).

Comment: I wouldn't call this syntactic sugar. "Default" join type, "shorthand," or "alias," maybe.

Comment: *In computer science, syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express*. I believe ability to omit `INNER` falls under this definition.

Comment: If you apply the definition very literally, yes, but I've always seen it reserved for more interesting types of syntax, not just alternative names for things.

Comment: @Quassnoi the mere fact that this question is asked, shows the absense of `INNER` does _not_ make the query easier to read. For all I know, `JOIN` could well mean `LEFT JOIN` if it wasn't cleared up by the answers here.

Comment: @Quassnoi Your comment's quoted introductory wiki statement is true of syntactic sugar, but it's inadequate as a definition. Syntactic sugaring is about simpler syntax for special cases of complex syntax. It is more appropriate to say that INNER is a "noise word".

Comment: This sounds like saying `long` is syntactic sugar for `signed long int` in C. It doesn't really feel like it's syntactically different because that typedef should just get collapsed into a single node by the lexer, so wouldn't it be the same syntax? IMO `...JOIN t2 USING (c1, c2)`  vs `...JOIN t2 ON (t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2)` is syntactic sugar.

Comment: @NickT: late to the party, but the `USING` clause can change the query semantics and influence the optimizer decisions. There is no easy substitute for, say, `a FULL JOIN b USING (id) FULL JOIN c USING (id)` without the `USING` clause. Unlike `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN`, which are even lexed to the same thing, `USING` is far beyond being just syntax sugar.

Answer (score 230):

INNER JOIN = JOIN

- INNER JOIN is the **default if you don't specify** the type when you use the word JOIN.

  You can also use LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN, in which case the word OUTER is optional, or you can specify CROSS JOIN.

OR

- For an INNER JOIN, the syntax is:

  ```
  SELECT ...
  FROM TableA
  [INNER] JOIN TableB
  ```

  (In other words, the INNER keyword is **optional**--results are the same with or without it.)

Answer (score 78):

> Does it differ between different SQL implementations?

Yes, [Microsoft Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) doesn't allow just `join`. It requires [`inner join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 61):

Similarly with `OUTER JOINs`, the word `"OUTER"` is optional. It's the `LEFT` or `RIGHT` keyword that makes the `JOIN` an `"OUTER" JOIN`.

However for some reason I always use `"OUTER"` as in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and never `LEFT JOIN`, but I never use `INNER JOIN`, but rather I just use `"JOIN"`:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ...
FROM MyTable AS T1
     JOIN MyOtherTable AS T2
         ON T2.ID = T1.ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN MyOptionalTable AS T3
         ON T3.ID = T1.ID
```

Comment: I am the opposite of you: I always say "INNER JOIN" but I never use OUTER; so "LEFT JOIN" and "RIGHT JOIN". Guess I'm just keeping my character counts constant!

Comment: you are going to have to explain this one.  How is "inner" and "outer" both optional keywords when leaving it off of both of them you end up with "join"?

Comment: @John Lord I use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" and "JOIN", never "INNER JOIN"

Answer (score 43):

As the other answers already state there is no difference in your example.

The relevant bit of grammar is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

```
<join_type> ::= 
    [ { INNER | { { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [ OUTER ] } } [ <join_hint> ] ]
    JOIN
```

Showing that all are optional. The page further clarifies that

> `INNER` Specifies all matching pairs of rows are returned. Discards
>   unmatched rows from both tables. **When no join type is specified, this
>   is the default**.

The grammar does also indicate that there is one time where the `INNER` *is* required though. When specifying a join hint.

See the example below

```
CREATE TABLE T1(X INT);
CREATE TABLE T2(Y INT);

SELECT *
FROM   T1
       LOOP JOIN T2
         ON X = Y;

SELECT *
FROM   T1
       INNER LOOP JOIN T2
         ON X = Y;
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

INNER JOIN is the same as JOIN.
There is no performance benefit or output difference.
Both give an intersection when used with an equivalent condition (like one column of a table equals one column of the second table) that is written in 'ON'.

This can be achieved according to old syntax also without using the word join altogether as shown below.

SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1=TABLE2.COLUMN4;

(Using random numbers for columns)

All the above three methods give exactly the same result.

Comment: This adds nothing to the many answers on this very old very voted Q&A. Moreover like most of the answers there is way more words than needed since the answer is just "No".