# Does "JOIN" mean the same as "INNER JOIN"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join)

I have found some legacy SQL (T-SQL) for MS SQL Server, which has a clause

```
TableA JOIN TableB
```

I was just wondering if this is identical to

```
TableA INNER JOIN TableB
```

or if there is any difference?

Also, if I were to port this to another database engine, e.g. MySQL, Access, Oracle, would JOIN also always mean the same as INNER JOIN?

Comment: You can lookup the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join

Comment: It was already asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join

Comment: Ah OK. I didn't spot that one. Apologies.

Comment: Access requires the `INNER` qualifier, I believe the others you mention do not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try it?

Quoted from palehorse:

> They function the same. `INNER JOIN` can be a bit more clear to read,
>   especially if your query has other join types (e.g. LEFT or RIGHT)
>   included in it.

Comment: I did try it, but just wanted to be sure there were no edge cases in which they might differ. Also apologies for asking a duplicate question.