# Inner join vs join

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join)

Did read this....but there is a difference if you look at my question. I have asked why DOES NOT THIS WORK......that link has all the explanations only.......

```
String sql ="SELECT s.text, s.postdate,"+
        "d.Fname FROM Wall s " +
        "join Kid_Register d on d.id=s.fromsl";// this works

String sql ="SELECT s.text, s.postdate,"+
        "d.Fname FROM Wall s " +
        "inner join Kid_Register d on d.id=s.fromsl"; // this does not
```

Can I know the reason why? As far as my research on the net it says that inner join and join are the same and as one put in SO the diff is just the "syntactical sugar" part....

Comment: @Siddiqui but the question is why is he getting no rows for the second version

Comment: @Bohemian, oh sorry, I have deleted my comment.

Comment: What version of SQL server do you use?

Comment: @KunalShah 5.0 what? What database are you testing this on?

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura It is MySQL  v.5.0.0

Comment: @astandr How is this a duplicate? Could you read my question...I dont want to know the difference, I want to know why does not it work.......