# what is the difference between join keyword and inner join keyword in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I can't find documentations on the key word `join` but I saw examples on the web using it.

I was doing some experiment with it in Oracle `hr` schema, where I have table `departments`:

- `deparment_name`
- `manager_id`
- `location_id`

A table `employees`:

- `first_name`
- `employee_id`

And table `locations`:

- `location_id`
- `city`

Query should return the department_name, first_name of the manager of the department, and the city where the department is located.

The code using the keyword `join` seem to return the some result in comparison to using the keyword `inner join`

Code with `join`:

```
select d.department_name, e.first_name,l.city
from departments d
   join employees e on d.manager_id=e.employee_id
   join locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id
```

Code with `inner join`:

```
select d.department_name, e.first_name,l.city
from departments d
   inner join employees e on d.manager_id=e.employee_id
   inner join locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id
```

Is there a difference between the two condition, or am I just happen to stumble on a situation where they return the same results?

Comment: asked before and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join  This isn't a critism on your post.  It's an indication that this has been asked before and has a quality answer there.

Comment: @xQbert: not about oracle though

Comment: @xQbert: so? What that answer is based on? Does oracle obliged to behave like sql server? You want to refer to a generic question - find one about ANSI SQL

Comment: @Community: the referred question **IS NOT** a duplicate, it's about another RDBMS which isn't assumed to behave similarly.

Comment: @xQbert: His answer (even though it's short and without any documentation based proofs) - is a particular answer for a particular question. Your reference - is a question about another RDBMS. And if you don't know both - you cannot say, if you may follow it or not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- Following 1992 ANSI SQL reference, [INNER is optional](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> Query expressions   179 7.5  - joined table
>
> 3) If a *qualified join* is specified and a *join type* is not
>               specified, then INNER is implicit.

- Following Oracle Standards (**9i onward**), the `INNER` prefix is also optional. Before 9i, Oracle didn't follow ANSI rules, and didn't even support `JOIN` syntax.