# best practice: Oracle SQL Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

which example below is best practice for inner joins? the examples below are
pretty simple but, what if there are multiple tables involved? 
which approach would you choose?

example queries:

simple

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, suppliers.supplier_name, orders.order_date
FROM suppliers, orders
WHERE suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id;
```

using keyword INNER JOIN

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, suppliers.supplier_name, orders.order_date
FROM suppliers
INNER JOIN orders
ON suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 1992 [ANSI](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) recommends the `JOIN` notation, and regarding to readability this is what I would recommend using.

Everything has been said on this topic, but I will just remind that from a logical point of view it makes much more sense to separate the join conditions from the value filters for 2 reasons:

- that's not the same thing at all
- Oracle internally (and mysql probably too, even though I don't really know) [first calculates intermediate recordsets](http://www.centrexcc.com/Joins,%20Skew%20and%20Histograms.pdf) and THEN, afterwards, applies the `WHERE` filters.

Comment: thanks! i was lost, now i am found.

Comment: +1 @Sebas - well stated, plus I happen to agree :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend explicitly stating JOIN type and using ON clause.
*But you need to use it correctly. In your example you forgot to include FROM clause and suppliers table.*

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, 
       suppliers.supplier_name, 
       orders.order_date
  FROM suppliers s INNER JOIN 
       orders o ON s.supplier_id = o.supplier_id;
```

Comment: Why are you typing `inner join` instead of `join`?  Are your work is priced based on code size?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff For the sake of readability. Do these five characters make a huge difference for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15892024/1291428

Comment: IMHO, it is more easily to read/understand more shorter version of text.  You are getting nothing concerning readability by prepending `inner` keyword.

Comment: It depends. It's like an emphase, INNER really insist visually on the fact that the result will be an intersection. But I agree with you, this is mostly a habbit thing and I myself have problems going ahead and leaving it behind. Please note that some (old and outdated) RDBMS don't accept the JOIN key word by itself.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It's subjective and a matter of preference. And one can always say that you win almost nothing not specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of functionalities both WHERE AND JOINS are same..

Comment: To be clear, both forms are joins, but one has the _join condition(s)_ in a WHERE clause while the other has the join condition(s) in an explicit ON clause.