# How to obtain specific data in a SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm very new to SQL and was wondering if someone could direct me on how to obtain specific rows of data using the WHERE clause of an SQL file. This is my current WHERE clause:

```
CREATE or REPLACE view V_Status1 
AS
    SELECT 
        A.C0401_aid, B.C0401_description DESCR, 
        A.c0432_date DATEREQUIRED, A.C0432_sampl_value_r
    FROM vhis_data A, T0401_accounts B
    WHERE A.C0401_aid = B.C0401_aid 
      AND (B.C0401_aid = 5486 OR B.C0401_aid = 5489 OR B.C0401_aid = 5490);
```

5486, 5489 and 5490 represent the accounts that I need data from, but my current clause does not make sense for what I want. I need the data from **all three accounts** not just one. Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: For starters: AND B.C0401_aid IN (5486,5489,5490)

Comment: Secondly, post the rest of your query. I suspect the issue lies in your table joins.

Comment: Like already mentioned, you'll want to post your full query, the results you are getting now, and what the result should look like.  Also, which database are you using?  MySQL or SQL Server? ...so that you can adjust the question's tag.

Comment: I have added the full query. Also sorry for the confusion and correct me if I'm wrong, but I am using Oracle.

Comment: The join is posted in the query.  `FROM vhis_data A, T0401_accounts B` is a `LEFT JOIN` by default, and the criteria is set in the `WHERE` clause.  This is not the recommended `JOIN` syntax, but it does work.

Comment: The values I need are telemetry values out in the field. I believe, my FROM clause is correct. I'm just having trouble with the WHERE clause to select the three accounts. I will try your suggestions @Matt

Comment: If your query (or the suggested answers) don't work, I suggest you check your data and verify the data you expect actually exists for these 3 accounts.

Comment: @dub stylee: It isn't a left join by default.  What makes you think that it is?

Comment: @dub stylee & sstan, technically it's a cartesian join until a connection is specified, either in the JOIN or WHERE clause.

Comment: I thought I had read somewhere that the default JOIN type if none is specified is a LEFT JOIN, but I see in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15892024/3101082 that the default JOIN in Oracle is INNER JOIN.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The query worked! Thank you ALL for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator

example:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Your case will looks like :

```
WHERE A.C0401_aid = B.C0401_aid AND
B.C0401_aid in(5486,5489,5490);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up the syntax, but this should perform the same operation your current query performs.

```
CREATE or REPLACE view V_GTAAStatus1 AS
SELECT A.C0401_aid, 
       B.C0401_description DESCR, 
       A.c0432_date DATEREQUIRED, 
       A.C0432_sampl_value_r [column_name]
FROM vhis_data A
LEFT JOIN T0401_accounts B on A.C0401_aid = B.C0401_aid
WHERE B.C0401_aid IN (5486,5489,5490);
```

Comment: See comment on @dubstylee's answer.

Comment: Well, I think it would be best to remove that. If anything, it looks buggy, because the `WHERE` clause invalidates the `LEFT JOIN` in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the legacy `JOIN` syntax.  @TinyOS answer is correct, here is your original query in the more accepted current syntax:

```
CREATE or REPLAC view V_GTAAStatus1 AS
SELECT A.C0401_aid, B.C0401_description DESCR, 
   A.c0432_date DATEREQUIRED, A.C0432_sampl_value_r
FROM vhis_data A
INNER JOIN T0401_accounts B ON A.C0401_aid = B.C0401_aid
WHERE B.C0401_aid IN (5486, 5489, 5490);
```

Comment: @Matt beat me to it.  Both queries should have the same result, the only difference being that using `INNER JOIN` will filter out any mismatching rows before the `WHERE` clause, while the `LEFT JOIN` will filter them out with the `WHERE` clause.