# Select all from table even null and join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to SELECT the all rows from meeting table even its null. My table structure:

```
attandance table:
id  | meeting_id  | person_id | time  
1   | 1           | 12        | 02:02
2   | 1           | 15        | 02:05
3   | 1           | 22        | 02:05
4   | 2           | 1         | 02:20
5   | 2           | 12        | 02:01
6   | 3           | 12        | 02:03

and meeting table:
id  | date       
1   | 15-12-2014           
2   | 17-12-2014   
3   | 19-12-2014
4   | 21-12-2014
```

The output should be:

If I SELECT the person_id 12 then it should return:

```
date       |time
15-12-2014 | 02:02
17-12-2014 | 02:01
19-12-2014 | 02:03
21-12-2014 | NULL
```

If I SELECT the person_id 1 then it should return:

```
date       |time
15-12-2014 | NULL
17-12-2014 | 02:20
19-12-2014 | NULL
21-12-2014 | NULL
```

Comment: You can learn how to perform outer joins [from this existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17946221/2359271).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a pretty straightforward outer join between the tables:

```
select
    m.id,
    m.date
    a.time,
    c.someColumn
from
    meetings m
        left outer join attendance a
            on m.id=a.meeting_id
            and a.person_id=:person
        left outer join someTable c
            on m.id=c.id
```

I have written a more detailed answer on these sorts of joins in the question and answer: [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Edit: As per the comment by Andrew, the clause for the personID is in the join rather than in a normal where clause because it is an outer join. If the condition was put into the where clause as normal, it would in fact negate the outer join completely.

Comment: Spot on.  You may want to explain why the constraint on person_id needs to be in the join clause.

Comment: Where'd you get that indentation style?

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh, this code is working, but in my code, i have 2 other join table thats make me cant get the result i wanted. I Left outer join 2 other table but still wont.

Comment: @SuSu As long as the condition is in the join and not a where clause you should be able to get what you want from the query. I added a bit more explanation as per Andrew's comment.

Comment: @AirThomas What's wrong with it? That's how I always write my queries so it is nice and easy to read :)

Comment: @Fluffeh It's just different from any styles I have seen before. Personally, I would rather see all the tables at the same indentation level, and increase the indentation when continuing a clause onto a new line (your first `on` clause). But I am sure it's fine to read when you are used to it.