# T-SQL - Performing a Join to Retrieve Counts of 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, aggregate-functions

I am working with a climate database that has three tables. An event table which holds the datetime that a weather event took place, the type of event and the state the event took place in. The second table is a fatality event table which is linked through an ID number from the first table. Finally, there is a table which holds a list of years (1950, 1951, 1952 etc.).

I've written the following:-

```
SELECT
    State,
    YEAR(BeginDate) as Year,
    COUNT(*) as CountOfEvents
FROM 
    [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_Event]
JOIN 
    [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_FatalityEvent] ON [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_Event].EventID = [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_FatalityEvent].EventID
WHERE 
    EventType like'%tornado%'
    AND YEAR(BeginDate) >= 1995 
    AND YEAR(BeginDate) <= 2014
GROUP BY 
    State, YEAR(BeginDate)
ORDER BY 
    State, YEAR(BeginDate)
```

which summarises the number of fatality events per month per state. The query above works but it omits any counts which return a count of 0.

I've attempted adding this line after reading about joins:-

```
RIGHT JOIN 
    [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_YearValues] ON YEAR([StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_Event].BeginDate) = [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_YearValues].[Year]
```

but this isn't returning 0's in the fields where the count of fatality events for that state and year is 0.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the requirement for the DT_YearValues?  It looks like you will be getting the year just fine using the `YEAR(x)` T-SQL function.

Comment: DT_YearValues was put in as a test to see if it would bring back all years for each state, even if the number of events for that state and year was 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming EventType is in [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_FatalityEvent]
the following would break a right join
where EventType like'%tornado%'

```
SELECT State,
       YEAR(BeginDate) as Year,
       COUNT([StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_FatalityEvent].[EventID]) as CountOfEvents
  FROM [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_Event]
 right JOIN [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_FatalityEvent] 
    ON [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_Event].[EventID] = [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_FatalityEvent].[EventID]
   and EventType like'%tornado%'
   AND YEAR(BeginDate) >= 1995 
   AND YEAR(BeginDate) <= 2014
 GROUP BY State, YEAR(BeginDate)
 ORDER BY State, YEAR(BeginDate)
```

You need to identify which table the columns are from

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for this. I understand what you mean about identifying columns to tables. EventType is part of the DT_Event table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a left join.  If your `DT_FatalityEvent` table only has records for fatality events you are performing an inner join, and it should probably be a left join as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Here is a sample of how I would code the query.  (NOTE:  I usually alias the tables so that it is easier to know which ones you are referring to in the `SELECT` clause).

I also am assuming you have a `NumberOfFatalities` for each event, in which case you might want to consider a `SUM` instead.

```
SELECT 
  A.State,
  YEAR(A.BeginDate) [Year],
  SUM(ISNULL(B.NumberOfFatalities,0)) [Fatalities]
FROM
  DT_Event A 
LEFT JOIN
  DT_FatalityEvent B ON A.EventId = B.EventID
WHERE 
  A.EventType like'%tornado%'
  AND YEAR(A.BeginDate) >= 1995 AND YEAR(A.BeginDate) <= 2014
GROUP BY 
  A.State, YEAR(A.BeginDate)
ORDER BY 
  A.State, YEAR(A.BeginDate)
```

This will ensure you get records from the DT_Event table even if there are no DT_FatalityEvent records with matching EventID's.  The NumberOfFatalities field (my guess) would be NULL in those cases, so you should probably ensure a value of 0 before using the `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the fast reply. I will definitely take on board what was said by Blam about using aliases as this make for much easier code, so thanks for the advice. I was making it too complex, and indeed as bigtlb said there was no need for a YearValues table.

This was the code that did what I needed!

```
SELECT
    A.State,
    YEAR(A.BeginDate),
    COUNT(B.EventID)
FROM [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_Event] A
LEFT JOIN [StormEvents].[dbo].[DT_FatalityEvent] B
    ON
        A.EventID = B.EventID
        AND A.EventType like '%tornado%'
GROUP BY State, YEAR(A.BeginDate)
ORDER BY State, YEAR(A.BeginDate)
```

Thanks for everyone' suggestions!
Mike.