# Fetch data from database from multiple tables one primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data from the `database`. I have three tables in my database like: `listing_master_residential`, `listing_master_condo` and `listing_master_commercial`.

There are three tables and there is one primary key `Ml_num` in all tables. I want to search the data form one table which matches `mls number` table.

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM listing_master_residential ,listing_master_commercial, listing_master_condo WHERE Ml_num=$option";
```

i want to show only those data to match `ml_num` in above table

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: here i am using cross join  but showing an error Column 'Ml_num' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

**Try This by using `inner join`:**

```
SELECT t1.Ml_num,t2.*,t3.Ml_num FROM listing_master_residential t1 
JOIN listing_master_commercial t2 ON t1.Ml_num = 'W2726470' 
JOIN listing_master_condo t3 ON t1.Ml_num = 'W2726470'
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: i want fetch all column where match my condition in above one table as a example my ml_num match with listing_master_commercial as all the field .

Comment: @avktech, so no issue you can fetch all the fields. I edted my answer please check.

Comment: $sql ="SELECT t1.Ml_num,t2.*,t3.Ml_num FROM listing_master_residential t1
JOIN listing_master_commercial t2 ON t1.Ml_num = $option
JOIN listing_master_condo t3 ON t1.Ml_num = $option";

Comment: showing a error Unknown column 'W2726470' in 'on clause'

Comment: @avktech, You doing in a wrong way. what is `$option` here ?

Comment: option here condition ml_num=W2726470  which table ml_num show data