# SQL FORM multiple tables - 'left join' vs ','

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

what is better? and why?

function a:

```
DELETE a FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
ON a.CHROM=b.CHROM AND a.POS=b.POS
```

function b:

```
DELETE a FROM a, b 
WHERE a.CHROM=b.CHROM AND a.POS=b.POS
```

Comment: First learn what joins do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins/448080#448080 obviously left join better than cross join

Comment: Really depends on what you are trying to acheive. See:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for left and full join

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: The explicit `LEFT JOIN` provides readability oppose to the latter approach. It is also clearer as to what conditions the tables are being joined on. Also, consistency is very important as mixing up explicit `JOIN` statements with the `,` approach can lead to undesired behaviors.

Comment: Left join is not the same of a cartesian product. You can get different results if `table_a left join table_b` if there are results in A without a match in B.

Comment: LEFT JOIN in a DELETE is just plain odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to join in the FROM clause because it gets executed first. There are cases where you should join in the where but not here. So I would say function a is your best bet. On a side note, I don't think you want to do a left join in function a because you will be joining more records than you will be deleting. It may be better and more efficient to use INNER JOIN in function a. A good practice is to select before you delete or update. If you run these selects do you get the same results? You should get more results in the first query because you are using left join and the second query is similar to an inner join.

```
SELECT a FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
ON a.CHROM=b.CHROM AND a.POS=b.POS 

SELECT a FROM a, b 
WHERE a.CHROM=b.CHROM AND a.POS=b.POS
```

check out this answer:

[INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

If need a better explanation on joins this was really helpful to me:

[SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)