# Querying two tables in phpmy admin

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have two tables in phpmyadmin posts and post_meta and the common column in both tables is post-id.

So I would like to create a query  where the results would should post-id, the email (from the post_meta) and title (from posts) Table.

I can get the query to work from individual table i.e i can get the list of all emails from the post_meta table but i can't seem to get the above.

I am trying to use sql query but i have no idea on where to start this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. In which meta, emails have been stored in post_meta table ?

Comment: email are stored in post_meta table. Ive' tried `SELECT *  FROM `post_meta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'email' and this displays all the emails

Comment: Try this :- SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value FROM wp_posts as p, wp_postmeta as pm where p.ID=pm.post_id

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins) will help you.

Comment: @Khushboo the above does not show the email addresses

Comment: what result you are getting ?

Comment: i am getting a table with id, post_title, meta_key and meta value, wht i want is id, post_title and email

Comment: email is a filedname in your wp_postmeta table ?

Comment: email is the field name i.e meta_key= email

Comment: SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value FROM wp_posts as p, wp_postmeta as pm where p.ID=pm.post_id and pm.email

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is a `JOIN` in your query.

Essentially, you need to try something like this:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, post_meta.email, posts.title
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_meta ON posts.post_id = post_meta.post_id
```

What this is doing is joining all rows in the post_meta table, to all rows in the posts table, where the post_id field matches.

This is all done dynamically, it doesn't alter your tables etc, but will return a result set giving you the post_id, the email address and the title of the post.

I hope this helps, please add some more detail if I have misunderstood.