# How to return data from two tables only when the column value in one table is same as another table using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and I want to return data from two tables only when the Mobile numbers in both the table are same. I don't want any `null` values. How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
Table A 
UserID  CandidateName  CurrentMobile  CurrentDistrict  Email      Centre 
1       Max            98234          Chennai          aaa@a.com  A
2       Raju           97364          Salem            bbb@b.com  B
3       Ramesh         99873          Trichy           ccc@c.com  C
```

```
Table B
Name     MobileNumber  District
Maximus  98234         Salem 
Ramesh   99873         Trichy
Venkat   98376         Chennai
```

I want the following result:

```
UserID  CandidateName  Name     CurrentDistrict  District  Email      Centre  MobileNumber 
1       Max            Maximus  Chennai          Salem     aaa@a.com  A       98234
3       Ramesh         Ramesh   Trichy           Trichy    ccc@c.com  C       99873
```

I tried to use `UNION`, but it gives `null` values in some columns and also returns all the data from both the tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to join the two tables, on the condition that `A.CurrentMobile` is the same as `B.MobileNumber`:

```
SELECT
  A.UserID,
  A.CandidateName,
  B.Name,
  A.CurrentDistrict,
  B.District,
  A.Email,
  A.Centre,
  B.MobileNumber
FROM
  A,
  B
WHERE
  A.CurrentMobile = B.MobileNumber
```

Alternatively you can use this syntax for the same result:

```
SELECT
  ... (all the same fields again)
FROM
  A
INNER JOIN B ON A.CurrentMobile = B.MobileNumber
```

The query will be much faster if you have an index on the two fields you use for the join (that is, the mobile number fields). Read more about joins [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins).