# Oracle JOIN ON colA = colB: how to include null rows from colA

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

**TABLE_A**

```
| SURNAME | COL_X |
```

**TABLE_B**

```
| ID | COL_Y |
```

COL_X can be mapped towards the ID column in table B, and I need the values from COL_Y.

The below query works fine except when COL_X in TABLE_A has a NULL value. I would like to include those rows. How do I do that?

```
SELECT a.SURNAME, b.COL_Y
FROM TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B b
ON a.COL_X = b.ID
```

I have tried the following query but it returns duplicate rows and can therefore not be used.

```
SELECT a.SURNAME, b.COL_Y
FROM TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B b
ON a.COL_X = b.ID or a.COL_X IS NULL
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use left join instead Inner join?

Comment: Just use `left join` instead of `inner join`. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins/21085546#21085546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried using an inner join which displays all rows from both tables. You can probably use the left join to do what you expect:

```
SELECT a.SURNAME, b.COL_Y
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b
  ON a.COL_X = b.ID
```

Comment: You are right about this. Your solution works for the problem I have presented. However there is another variable which I should have shown from the start. The ON clause should exclude other rows in TABLE_A, like this: ON a.COL_Z = 'Z' and (here's what I showed) a.COL_X = b.ID. A left join resolves the issue with the second section, but also seems to ignore that COL_Z needs to equal 'Z'. Do you have any idea about that? Sorry for the confusion. You resolved the presented issue anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.SURNAME, b.COL_Y
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b
  ON a.COL_X = b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try an outer join, for example -

```
SELECT a.SURNAME, b.COL_Y
FROM TABLE_A a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
ON a.COL_X = b.ID or a.COL_X IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Those rows will have no corespondent in tableB. The query is simple:

```
SELECT a.SURNAME, b.COL_Y
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b
ON a.COL_X = b.ID
```

Read this for more about joins: [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins/21085546#21085546)