# How to create a result set with a list of all users, duplicated for each location

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a users table and a locations table.

The locations table looks like:

```
Location
-id
-name
```

I want an output that has all users, repeated for each location so like:

```
user1 location1
user2 location1
user3 location1
user1 location2
user2 location2
user3 location2
```

How can I create a SELECT query like the above?

Comment: `SELECT u.name, l.name FROM users u,location l`

Comment: `Select * from location cross join users`  one of my favorite [links](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for join types and explainations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [cross join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT Users.Name, Locations.Name
FROM Users 
    CROSS JOIN Locations
```