# SQL Server Data in one table, but missing from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce, sql-query-store

This isn't as simple as the title. (What is an appropriate title?) I think the easiest way to describe my issue is with an example.

**My goal is a list of what color balloon’s each child is missing.**

Let’s assume table 1 contains the following data in 2 columns:

> *Child BalloonColor*
>
> - Sally  Yellow
> - Sally  White
> - Sally  Blue
> - Bob        Red
> - Bob        Green
> - Bob        White

This is table 2, also 2 columns.

> *ColorCode    Color*
>
> - Y         Yellow
> - W         White
> - R         Red
> - B         Blue
> - G         Green
> - P         Pink

I need a write a result set that states what color balloon each child needs to have all colors.

> - Sally, R, Red
> - Sally, G, Green
> - Sally, P, Pink
> - Bob, Y, Yellow
> - Bob, B, Blue
> - Bob, P, Pink

My example is small, but assume I have a 1000 children in my table 1 and 75 colors in table 2. How can I check each child, one at a time, is my ultimate question?  A `Not in` query will only yield "P, Pink", but you can see I need it at the child level, not table level.

I'm not a developer, but can write good SQL statements.

MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: You just need a basic join for this. The Color table should be basis of your query. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: You have a flaw with this table structure. If a child has no balloons at all yet and hence has no row in table1 they should require all balloon colours but because there is no row in table 1 we don't know about them. I think you need a table with just the children's names in it

Comment: Great catch, but every child is given at least 1 balloon.  Thus this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    SQ.child_name,
    BC.balloon_color
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        child_name
    FROM
        Child_Balloons
    ) SQ
CROSS JOIN Balloon_Colors BC
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Child_Balloons CB
        WHERE
            CB.child_name = SQ.child_name AND
            CB.balloon_color = BC.balloon_color
    )
```

Comment: Cross Joins are new to me.  But I think this might be my answer!  I'll test it and let ya'll know.  Thanks Tom H, for the sql query.

Comment: A `CROSS JOIN` basically says, "Give me every possible combination of rows between the two tables." They aren't used a lot, because you usually don't want to explode data out like that. This sort of problem is one of the exceptions because you want to start with every combination of children/balloon colors to see which are then missing.

Comment: Hackerman, you're missing Bob, from you results.  This is my issue.  Tom H, thanks.  Yes, it's a lot of data and in my results, I need to pair it down some, but this is huge step in the right direction.

Comment: @hackerman and Tom H...THANK YOU!!!  With both your explainations and answers, I was able to get my desired result set!