# Assistance With query across 2 tables within specified date range

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables in a large SQL Database and i need to query across them and I am struggling TBH. Here are the parameters:

```
Table 1 - Live Policies
Table 2 - Email Addresses
```

Common Pivot = Client number which is present in both tables.

From Table 1 i need to retrieve the following fields:

```
Client Number
Ref Number
Name 
Postcode
Inception date
Policy Type (= 'PC')

 Select Client, Ptype, Ref, Incep, [Name], Postcode from [Live
 Policies] where Ptype = 'PC'
```

This works fine.

From Table 2 i need to retrieve:

```
Webaddr
```

My question is how do i return the email address for the required records from the second table by referencing the client number? (client number is the same for all records) The second part of the statement is where i'm getting stuck.. I'm aware of the JOIN statement but if i try this i just get nowhere.. Help most appreciated!

Comment: You need to work a litle more in your question, Provide the complete schema for the tables involve, Include some sample data and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't provide any sample data due to data protection issues (client data) but here are the table structures: Table 1 - Live.Policies - Column Name
Column Name
Occup
NetR
Name
LtranDat
LTADate
IPT%
Inv
Incep
Grp
Freq
Forename
Fee
Disc%
Desc
Comm%
Co
Client
Cbran
Canc
Balance
Addr4
Addr3
Addr2
Addr1

Comment: The sample doesn't have to be real.  See this [page from the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on generating a good example.

Comment: I already give you an answer. But if you read the link I provide you will find this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You can make some sample data to make your question more clear.

Comment: Table 2 - MIS_I_C26 coloumn Name Column Name
WORK
WEBADDR
USERNAME
Sect
Ref
PK_ID
PASSWORD
Line
LETTER
Key
HOME
EMAIL
Date
Client
Bran

Comment: @MartinTaylor Dont put it on the comment, just edit your question and leave a comment like `I include the desire information`

Comment: Why do you "get nowhere" with the JOIN?   Do you get an error?   Post your attempt to use JOIN, and what result you get from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 0):

USE a **[JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)**

```
 select L.Client, L.Ptype, L.Ref, L.Incep, L.[Name], L.Postcode, E.Webaddr
 from [Live Policies] as L
 JOIN [Email Addresses] as E
    ON L.Client = E.Client
 where Ptype = 'PC'
```