# How to return Homework Title using foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am pretty new to SQL but I have a task where I have three table that look like this;

[image]

Where there is a foreign key linking each (Classid -> Classid) (CurrenthomeworkID -> homeworkID)

I need to return the homework title, how would I do this?

Comment: This is basically the how version of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins) question.

Comment: That question only describes it for two tables, I need to return from the third table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins) all three tables together and select from any one of them:

```
SELECT u.userid, c.classid, h.homeworkTitle FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Classes AS c ON u.ClassID = c.ClassID
LEFT JOIN Homeworks AS h ON c.CurrenthomeworkID = h.homeworkID
```