# SQL Server - JOIN results

Tags: sql-server, left-join

Can we say in SQL Server, Inner Join = Left Join with NOT NULL filter?
Like in below example, both returns same result.

```
declare @a table(aid int, name varchar(10))
insert into @a values (1,'Jay'),(2,'John'),(3,'Kevin')

declare @b table(bid int, aid int, [status] varchar(5))
insert into @b values (1, 2,'Y'),(2, 2,'N'),(3, 3, 'NA')

select a.*,b.bid from @a a inner join @b b on a.aid = b.aid
select a.*,b.bid from @a a left join @b b on a.aid = b.aid where b.bid is not null
```

Comment: Correct! All the time

Comment: Got it, Thanks Dhruv!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins