# How to merge two tables in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables T1 and T2.

Table T1

```
Id   Value1

1    2
2    1
3    2
```

Table T2

```
Id   Value2

1    3
2    1
4    1
```

I need a SQL SERVER query to return the following

```
Id   Value1   Value2
1    2        3
2    1        1
3    2        0
4    0        1
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by **FULL OUTER JOIN** with **ISNULL**

Execution with given sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Id INT, Value1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Id INT, Value2 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (1, 3), (2, 1), (4, 1)

SELECT ISNULL(T1.Id, T2.Id) AS Id, 
       ISNULL(T1.Value1, 0) AS Value1, 
       ISNULL(T2.Value2, 0) AS Value2
FROM @Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
```

Result:

```
Id   Value1   Value2
1    2        3
2    1        1
3    2        0
4    0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI - `Merge` means something different in SQL Server.

I would suggest if you have a table which contains a list of all possible Id values, I would select everything from that and have two left outer joins to T1 and T2.

Assuming there isn't one, with only what is provided, it sounds like you want a full outer join.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT Id = COALESCE(T1.Id, T2.Id),
       Value1 = COALESCE(T1.Value1, 0),
       Value2 = COALESCE(T2.Value2, 0)
FROM   T1
       FULL OUTER JOIN T2
                    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a basic `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.id,t2.id) as [ID],
       coalesce(t1.value1,0) as Value1,
       coalesce(t2.value2,0) as Value2
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2
 ON(t1.id = t2.id)
```

This will join both table together, and will keep the record from both tables even when there is no match.

The `COALESCE()` is used to replace null values, because of the full join.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Its working fine with SQL Server 2012.

```
--Create two temp tables
    CREATE TABLE #temp1 
    (Id int,Value1 int)

    CREATE TABLE #temp2 
    (Id int,Value2 int)
--Insert Values to two tables
    INSERT INTO #temp1
    (Id,Value1)
    VALUES
    (1,2),(2,1),(3,3)

    INSERT INTO #temp2
    (Id,Value2)
    VALUES
    (1,3),(2,1),(4,1)
--Query which gives desired output
    SELECT 
        ID = COALESCE(#temp1.Id, #temp2.Id),
        Value1 = COALESCE(#temp1.Value1, 0),
        Value2 = COALESCE(#temp2.Value2, 0)
    FROM   
        #temp1 FULL JOIN #temp2 ON #temp1.Id = #temp2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general syntax for full join.

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM Table1 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE condition
```