# SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I need to make an sql SELECT statement where I will join tables(or get the value from joined table) only if condition is met, is this possible ?

I have an order table where I have user IDs, but I also have random generated IDs for users who ordered as guests. And I want to join users table on orders table, with that ID, but when the ID is randomly generated I want to return only values from order table because there are not records in user table for that ID.

I have only this, which will write rows where user_id exists in both tables

```
$sql = "SELECT orders.id_o, orders.user_id, orders.price, users.username 
FROM orders JOIN users 
ON orders.user_id = users.id  
ORDER BY order_date ASC";
```

Comment: left join, not inner join

Comment: Can the title gain some creativity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `left join`s are for. To answer the followup question in the comments, you can use `coalesce` to replace the `null`s returned from the left join:

```
SELECT    orders.id_o, orders.user_id, orders.price, 
          COALESCE(users.username, 'Guest')
FROM      orders
LEFT JOIN users ON orders.user_id = users.id  
ORDER BY  order_date ASC
```

Comment: and you could dupehammer

Comment: Thanks, it works nice. Is it possible to set default values for fields where nothing returned ? (eg. if its random generated ID username field will be blank, and i would like to set the default value to Guest)

Comment: @rtom One elegant way would be to use `coalesce`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly, just change to `left join`

```
    $sql = "SELECT orders.id_o, orders.user_id,orders.price, users.username 
    FROM orders Left JOIN users 
    ON orders.user_id = users.id  
    ORDER BY order_date ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

The following statement should do it:

```
SELECT
 orders.id_o,
 orders.user_id,
 orders.price,
 users.username 

FROM orders

LEFT JOIN users 
  ON orders.user_id = users.id
```

ORDER BY order_date ASC