# What's are the types of JOINS will support in Mysql?Is there any possible way to do this?

Tags: mysql

- How to do full joins in mysql?  and what are the types of joins will
     support in mysql.
- Im a begginer in mysql please help me solve this issue.

  Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you simply take a look into the documentation. Thanks. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: please dont mine...i want to know difference between outer join and full outer join..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before asking this question, I am assuming that you have not searched the net for anything at all, let alone MySQL documentation. Because I have asked stupid questions in the past (without researching enough), I am going to answer this one. By the way, this is a habit you must work upon. You should search for material, read and try solutions to your problems before coming to Stack Exchange.

Here's a snapshot from [Official MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

[image: From MySQL Documentation]

Apart from this, here are a few links that would help you understand JOINs, in general:

1. [Coding Horror's Visual Explanation of JOINs](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)
2. [Stack Overflow - SQL JOINs and their types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)
3. [One of the most popular posts on Stack Overflow - Difference between Inner and Outer JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

I think this would suffice for the basic knowledge of JOINs. You'd have to read more about what JOIN to use when - based on the data you want to fetch and also how your database management system (in this case, MySQL) [works with JOINs internally to optimize performance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-determining-join-type.html).

Comment: Sorry , i searched but i can't understand .so don't mine .thank you  @MontyPython

Comment: That's perfectly alright. We're all here to learn and help each other :)

Comment: ya offcourse thank you again but all putting negative votes ..

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you got your question answered :)

Comment: hmm, its ok ...