# SQL: If there is No match on condition (row in table) return a default value and Rows which match from different tables

Tags: sql

I have three tables: `Clinic`, `Stock` and `StockLog`.

I need to get all rows `where Stock.stock < 5`. I need to also show if an order has been placed and what amount it is; which is found in the table `Stocklog`.

The issue is that a user can set his stock level in the `Stock` table without placing an order which would go to `Stocklog`.

I need a query that can : return the rows in the `Stock` table and get the related order amounts in the `Stocklog` table. If no order has been placed in `StockLog`, then set amount to order amount to zero.

I have tried :

```
SELECT 
    Clinic.Name, 
    Stock.NameOfMedication, Stock.Stock, 
    StockLog.OrderAmount
FROM 
    Clinic
JOIN 
    Stock ON Stock.ClinicID = Clinic.ClinicID
JOIN  
    StockLog ON StockLog.StockID = Stock.StockID
WHERE 
    Stock.Stock <= 5
```

The issue with my query is that I lose rows which are not found in `StockLog`.

Any help on how to write this.

Thank you.

Comment: Try right join on stocklog

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking the query should look like this:

```
SELECT c.Name, s.NameOfMedication, s.Stock,
       COALESCE(sl.OrderAmount, 0) as OrderAmount
FROM Stock s LEFT JOIN
     Clinic c
     ON s.ClinicID = c.ClinicID LEFT JOIN
     StockLog sl
     ON sl.StockID = s.StockID
WHERE s.Stock <= 5 ;
```

You want to keep all rows in `Stock` (subject to the `WHERE` condition).  So think:  "make `Stock` the first table in the `FROM` and use `LEFT JOIN` for all the other tables."

Comment: Thank you so much... It worked 100% like I needed it to

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the rows that result from joining Clinic and Stock, then use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with StockLog. I don't know which SQL you're using (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle), so I can't give you a precise example, but searching for "left outer join" in the relevant documentation should work.

See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins) for an explanation of the various kinds of joins.