# SQL JOIN doesn't find guests, only users

Tags: sql, join

I am using this line of SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb_online.ip, tb_users.id, tb_online.login, tb_online.page 
FROM tb_online
JOIN tb_users 
  ON tb_online.login=tb_users.username 
ORDER BY login ASC
```

The problem is that this line `ON tb_online.login=tb_users.username` means that SQL query only selects users but not guests (*they don't have username in the `tb_users` table*).

How could I make SQL query to **select both users and guests**?

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Click on the [sql] tag, read the info. It includes guides like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: just use `left join` ....

Answer (score 1):

use `left join`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb_online.ip, tb_users.id, tb_online.login, tb_online.page 
FROM tb_online
LEFT JOIN tb_users 
  ON tb_online.login=tb_users.username 
ORDER BY login ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Lukas You are welcome