# Doctrine select all users that manage other users via column

Tags: doctrine

Maybe I am missing something completely, but I cannot get it working. I only want to select User objects that are linked to User objects.

User:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


// other fields ...



/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 */
private $firstManager;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 */
private $secondManager;

}
```

I want to select those who are firstManager or secondManager for a User. Sounds simple eh?

I thought, this would do:

```
public function findAllManagers()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
        ->join('user.firstManager', 'first_manager')
        ->join('user.secondManager', 'second_manager')
        ->orWhere('first_manager = user')
        ->orWhere('second_manager = user');
    $qb = $qb->getQuery();

    return $qb->getResult();
}
```

But only got one result, not all three I needed. I think this is valid SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what i see your sql query should look like:

```
SELECT user.* FROM user_table user
INNER JOIN user_table first_manager ON first_manager.id = user.first_manager_id
INNER JOIN user_table second_manager ON second_manager.id = user.second_manager_id
WHERE first_manager.id = user.id
OR second_manager.id = user.id
```

The result of this would be users who are their own first or second manager.

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
public function findAllManagers()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->leftJoin('u1', 'AppBundle\Entity\User', 'WITH', m = u1.firstManager)
        ->leftJoin('u2', 'AppBundle\Entity\User', 'WITH', m = u2.secondManager)
        ->where('u1.firstManager IS NOT NULL')
        ->orWhere('u2.secondManager IS NOT NULL')
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    return $qb->getResult();
}
```

The equivalent SQL query should be:

```
SELECT m.* FROM user_table m
LEFT JOIN user_table u1 ON u1.first_manager_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN user_table u2 ON u2.second_manager_id = m.id
WHERE u1.first_manager_id IS NOT NULL
OR u2.second_manager_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Exactly! Didn't know the `WITH` command in a leftJoin statement. I think I add `DISTINCT` so I do not get duplicated results.

Comment: The entityManager will handle duplication. The WITH keyword allows you to hard code the ON clause of the final SQL query. It is really useful on reverse-side of unidirectional mapping

Answer (score 0):

`->join()` results in an `INNER JOIN`. As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins), this will only give results, that are "in the center". If you have multiple `JOIN`s, this will only give results of all those joined tables. In your case, this means users that are firstManager and secondManager.

If you change to `->leftJoin()`, this will give you all users (with additional info), so it is a good place to start. Then you can filter those out that are neither firstManager or secondManager.

Something like this should work (untested)

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
   ->leftJoin('user.firstManager', 'fm')
   ->leftJoin('user.secondManager', 'sm')
   ->where('fm.id IS NOT NULL')
   ->orWhere('sm.id IS NOT NULL')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: With the 'left join' clause it can either have 0, 1 or 2 managers. With the 'where' clause, when at least 1 manager exists, it must have an id (it is always the case). So, your basically selecting all the users here.

Comment: If you just left join, you will have `NULL` rows (except for user of course, but with no relation) - [like here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda880/3). But if you add the `WHERE` clause, these will disappear ([code](https://pastebin.com/aQX6jW2t) - somehow sqlfiddle won't run it, but works).

Comment: By the way, the resulting SQL of the posted DQL is exactly the same as yours

Comment: You got the same SQL query than my second one ? It feels really weird...

Comment: Thanks kero, however what I want are those firstManagers and secondManagers objects. With your query I get those users _that have a manager_. But I want those managers only. I want all users that are manager, hence my functionname: `findAllManagers'

Comment: See the answer of OlivierC, you where going in the in te right direction, but the twist added by OlivierC did the job!