# inner join can have null column

Tags: sql, null, outer-join

I try to understand outer join and I got a question.

Assuming that all the columns are not null, after this query:

```
SELECT a.service_type_id, b.customer_member_id, a.service_name
FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE_TYPE a,
     MEMBER_CUSTOMER_SERVICES b
WHERE a.service_type_id = b.service_type_id;
```

Is it possible to get null fields in one of the column?

Comment: your sample query is INNER JOIN which will check for match of service_type_id from both table. there will be no null values on the columns. if you use OUTER JOIN and there are data that didn't match your criteria (a.service_type_id = b.service_type_id) then there will be nulls on the columns.

Comment: you can check this link about JOINS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: There is no OUTER JOIN in your query. Comma (`,`) is CROSS JOIN (with lower precedence than INNER/CROSS/OUTER JOIN), which is INNER JOIN ON 1=1. Please edit your question so that the title, text and code agree.

Answer (score 2):

First, the title to your question says "outer join", but your query is an inner join.

Second, the query is malformed, using an archaic syntax.  It should really be:

```
SELECT cs.service_type_id, mcs.customer_member_id, cs.service_name
FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE_TYPE cs JOIN
     MEMBER_CUSTOMER_SERVICES mcs
     ON cs.service_type_id = mcs.service_type_id;
```

Third, the answer to your question is "no".  None of the columns can be `NULL` if none of the source columns are `NULL` in your query.  If it were really an `OUTER JOIN`, then columns could be `NULL`.

Notes:

- *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- You table aliases should be abbreviations for the column names, rather than meaningless letters.