# SQL queries on creating a list in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which i need to ranked of a certain genre list according to descending order.

```
Documentary(Title, Duration, language, Genre)

Rating(LoginNames, Rating)
```

I am suppose to create a list for a certain genre in descending order of the rating.

I came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM Genre, Rating 
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

I am not to sure whether I will get the correct outcome of the result. Thank You!

Comment: If you are trying to order by rating, wouldn't you... order by rating?

Comment: There doens't seem to be a field in both tables to join them.

Comment: I have to select a specific genre from the documentary and then rank it according to descending order.

Comment: SunJ, what is the desired output? As @isaace pointed out, these tables cannot be joined together. I would assume that the Rating table needs a column for DocumentaryID (which I hope has a corresponding key in Documentary)?

Comment: @kchason@Jacob H, Oh yes i forgot to include that both has DocumentaryID as primary key which link both table together. Sorry for the omission. Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

With your comment update:

```
SELECT
    DocumentaryTbl.Title,
    DocumentaryTbl.Genre,
    RatingTbl.Rating,
    ... -- I would avoid *, choose the columns you'd like
FROM
   Documentary AS DocumentaryTbl
LEFT JOIN
   Rating AS RatingTbl
   ON DocumentaryTbl.DocumentaryID = RatingTbl.DocumentaryID
ORDER BY
   RatingTbl.Rating DESC; -- Or whichever column(s) you want to sort by
```

Comment: I am quite confused with the part after LEFT JOIN....., Do you mid to explain more in detail. Thank you!

Comment: Which part is confusing you? From your comment, both tables have a `DocumentaryID`, which is how you're joining the tables. Whether you use `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` depends on your desired behavior which you should look into in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins

Comment: The link you provided is in detail, I will read through the post, really appreciate your timing in answering this.Thank you!