# How to write this basic inner join SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

This is my `posts` table:

```
+-----+----------------+-------------+
| ID  |   post_title   | post_status |
+-----+----------------+-------------+
| 105 | Red Shirt      | active      |
| 106 | Green Shoes    | active      |
| 107 | Blue Hat       | hidden      |
+-----+----------------+-------------+
```

This is my `meta` table:

```
+-----------+------+
| object_id | lang |
+-----------+------+
|       105 | en   |
|       106 | fr   |
|       107 | en   |
+-----------+------+
```

I am trying to write an SQL query that returns the ID's of all the `posts` with the `post_status` of `active` AND the `lang` `en`. With these two tables, there should only be one result (`105`).

I am having trouble matching the `ID` to `object_id`. Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what  trouble are you having? please show us your query?

Comment: Brian check an answer posted by me whether it fulfill your requirement or not

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM posts p, meta m
WHERE p.ID = m.object_id
AND p.post_status = 'active'
AND m.lang='en'
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables and then specify the conditions:

```
SELECT posts.ID
FROM posts
INNER JOIN meta ON meta.object_id = posts.id
WHERE posts.post_status = 'active'
  AND meta.lang = 'en'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you only want those rows that have records in *both* tables, you want an `INNER JOIN`. There is a good post about different join types here: [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

For your query, you want the following:

```
SELECT
    PostTbl.ID -- The column(s) you want to select
FROM
    `posts` AS PostTbl -- I prefer aliasing every table so I keep the habit when self joining
INNER JOIN -- Since we want only the rows with records in both tables
    `meta` AS MetaTbl
    ON PostTbl.ID = MetaTbl.object_id -- The conditions on which we want the tables to join
WHERE
    PostTbl.post_status = 'active' -- Post is 'active'
    AND MetaTbl.lang = 'en'; -- Language is 'en'
```