# Is there a way in sql to use join, but in the results returned, to fetch all rows joined and not joined?

Tags: sql

Below is my database structure.

**users**

```
id|username|email               |country|datenumber|
--|--------|-----               |-------|----------|
 1|user1   |example@example.com | GB    |2017-11-08| 
 2|user2   |example@example.com | GB    |2017-11-08| 
 3|user3   |example@example.com | GB    |2017-11-08| 
 4|user4   |example@example.com | GB    |2017-11-08| 
 5|user5   |example@example.com | GB    |2017-11-08|
```

**faillogs**

```
id|userid  |type        |datenumber|
--|--------|------------|----------|
 1|1       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 2|3       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 3|3       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 4|3       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 5|5       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 6|5       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 7|5       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 8|5       |wronganswer |2017-11-08| 
 9|5       |wronganswer |2017-11-08|
```

**cashouts**

```
id|userid  |amount      |datenumber|
--|--------|------------|----------|
 1|1       |1.47        |2017-11-08| 
 1|1       |2.97        |2017-11-08| 
 1|2       |1.05        |2017-11-08|
```

My question is asking, how I can fetch all the users which have joined but also list a count of faillogs.

The below SQL fetches all the users

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

The SQL below does a join to fetch the faillogs.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(faillogs.userid) FROM users    
INNER JOIN faillogs 
ON users.id=faillogs.userid               
GROUP BY faillogs.userid                          
ORDER BY users.datenumber ASC
```

I would like the benefits of being able to fetch a count of the faillogs for each user with a join WITH the added benefit of showing all users, not just the users that have a faillog. How do I do this?

I have a SQL fiddle here.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56cf4/4

Comment: Just change your INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN and you're golden.

Comment: You GROUP BY usage is invalid SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql/mariadb. I could use GROUP BY on the sqlfiddle link I gave. I tested it in sqlfiddle and it worked, before putting it in the question.

Comment: I'm new to joins. Time to refer to this classic question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17946221/337306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. Also grouped by `users.id` instead of `faillogs.userid` since some of those could/will be `NULL`.

```
SELECT users.id, 
       users.username, 
       users.email, 
       users.country, 
       users.datenumber, 
       Count(faillogs.userid) 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN faillogs 
              ON users.id = faillogs.userid 
GROUP  BY users.id, 
          users.username, 
          users.email, 
          users.country, 
          users.datenumber 
ORDER  BY users.datenumber ASC
```

Comment: (Invalid GROUP BY according to most dbms.) Just saw you copied the original query's select list...

Comment: @jarlh good catch. I was just going purely off of his fiddle and didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

you must use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`