# Get Max Value of Column out of a a query list in Python

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am new to Python and am currently trying to create a Web-form to edit customer data. The user selects a customer and gets all DSL-Products linked to the customer. What I am now trying is to get the maximum downstream possible for a customer. So when the customer got DSL1, DSL3 and DSL3 then his MaxDownstream is 550. Sorry for my poor english skills.

Here is the structure of my tables..

```
Customer_has_product:
Customer_idCustomer | Product_idProduct
----------------------------
1                 |       1
1                 |       3
1                 |       4
2                 |       5
3                 |       3

Customer:
idCustomer | MaxDownstream
----------------------------
1         |       
2         |       
3         |       


Product:
idProduct | Name            | downstream
-------------------------------------------------
1         | DSL1            | 50
2         | DSL2            | 100
3         | DSL3            | 550
4         | DSL4            | 400
5         | DSL5            | 1000
```

And the code i've got so far:

```
db_session = Session(db_engine)
customer_object = db_session.query(Customer).filter_by(
    idCustomer=productform.Customer.data.idCustomer
).first()
productlist = request.form.getlist("DSLPRODUCTS_PRIVATE")
oldproducts = db_session.query(Customer_has_product.Product_idProduct).filter_by(
    Customer_idCustomer=customer_object.idCustomer)
id_list_delete = list(set([r for r, in oldproducts]) - set(productlist))
for delid in id_list_delete:
    db_session.query(Customer_has_product).filter_by(Customer_idCustomer=customer_object.idCustomer,
                                                    Product_idProduct=delid).delete()
db_session.commit()
for product in productlist:
    if db_session.query(Customer_has_product).filter_by(
        Customer_idCustomer=customer_object.idCustomer,
        Product_idProduct=product
    ).first() is not None:
        continue
    else:
        product_link_to_add = Customer_has_product(
            Customer_idCustomer=productform.Customer.data.idCustomer,
            Product_idProduct=product
        )
            db_session.add(product_link_to_add)
            db_session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is [`JOIN` the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17946221) onto each other. All relational database engines support joins, as does `SQLAlchemy`.

## So how do you do that in SQLAlchemy?

You have two options, really. One is to use the `Query` builder of SQLAlchemy's ORM, the other is using SQLAlchemy Core (upon which the ORM is built) directly. I really prefer the later, because it maps more directly to `SELECT` statements, but I'm going to show both.

### Using SQLAlchemy Core

How to do a `join` in Core is documented [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html?highlight=select#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.join). First argument is the table to JOIN to, second argument is the JOIN-condition.

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func

query = select(
    [
        Customer.idCustomer,
        func.max(Product.downstream),
    ]
).select_from(
    Customer.__table__
    .join(Customer_has_product.__table__,
          Customer_has_product.Customer_idCustomer ==
              Customer.idCustomer)
    .join(Product.__table__,
          Product.idProduct == Customer_has_product.Product_idProduct)
).group_by(
    Customer.idCustomer
)

# Now we can execute the built query on the database.
result = db_session.execute(query).fetchall()
print(result)  # Should now give you the correct result.
```

### Using SQLAlchemy ORM

To simplify this it's best to declare some [relationship`s on your models][2].`join`is documented [here][2]. First argument to`join` is the model to join onto and the second argument is the JOIN-condition again.

Without the relationships you'll have to do it like this.

```
result = (db_session
    .query(Customer.idCustomer, func.max(Product.downstream))
    .join(Customer_has_product,
          Customer_has_product.Customer_idCustomer ==
              Customer.idCustomer)
    .join(Product,
          Product.idProduct == Customer_has_product.Product_idProduct)
    .group_by(Customer.idCustomer)
).all()
print(result)
```

This should be enough to get the idea on how to do this.