# Relating two data-frames with different size in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text

I want to relate two data-frames with different size.

A simplified example of my data is as follow:

```
unigrams = c("the", "one", "can", "just","know", "now", "time", "but")
uni.freq = c(1304, 802, 715, 686, 428, 413, 663, 320)

bigrams = c("know i", "now i", "time i", "but i")
first.word = c("know", "now", "time", "but")
bi.freq = c(60, 58, 57, 56)

df.unigrams = data.frame(unigrams, uni.freq)
df.bigrams = data.frame(bigrams, bi.freq, first.word)
```

I want to add a column to df.bigrams, to show the frequency of words in the df.unigrams data-frame so it looks like this:

```
  bigrams bi.freq first.word   freq
 1  know i      60       know    428
 2   now i      58        now    413
 3  time i      57       time    663
 4   but i      56        but    320
```

I have tried a few things (grep, subsetting), but no luck. Any help for this beginner will be much appreciated.

```
df.bigrams$freq = subset(df.unigrams, df.unigrams$unigrams == df.bigrams$first.word)
```

Comment: `merge(df.bigrams, df.unigrams, by.x = "first.word", by.y = "unigrams")`

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourself [with the different types of joins (merges)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17946221/903061), it's good to know.