# MYSQL Combine 2 queries

Tags: mysql

Im very new to SQL, thus excuse if this sounds stupid.
I have two queries.

**First**

```
SELECT
  Tap_Back.*
FROM Tap_Back
WHERE Tap_Back.time > '2018-01-23'
```

**Second**

```
SELECT  
  readingdates.readdate  
FROM readingdates  
WHERE readingdates.readdate <= CURRENT_DATE()  
ORDER BY readingdates.readdate DESC  
LIMIT 1
```

Thus instead of hard coding the date  in the First , I want to read it from a different table.

Comment: I would recommend to first learn Relational Algebra. Seems that what you want to do is a basic relational algebra operation (join). You can check this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will definitely spend some time studying that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Tap_Back.* 
FROM Tap_Back 
WHERE Tap_Back.time > (SELECT readingdates.readdate
  FROM readingdates
  WHERE readingdates.readdate <= CURRENT_DATE()
  ORDER BY readingdates.readdate DESC
  LIMIT 1)
```

or my preference would be

```
SELECT Tap_Back.* 
FROM Tap_Back 
WHERE Tap_Back.time > (SELECT min(readingdates.readdate)
  FROM readingdates
  WHERE readingdates.readdate <= CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect.