# Query to select a row from a table from another using id

Tags: android, sql

I have two tables A and B. A has columns a,b,c,d,e,f and B has columns a and g. How can I get the row from table A according to the value of 'a' from Table B?

Comment: You can try this query "SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A on A.a = B.a WHERE B.a = yourinput"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simple join query

```
Select A.a From A inner join B on A.a=B.a
```

if need extra condition

```
Select A.a From A inner join B on A.a=B.a where B.a=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.e, a.f, b.g
FROM A a,
INNER JOIN B b ON a.a = b.a
WHERE a.a = b.a
```

These are the basics of SQL, next time try to read up on the basics first.
You can go here [W3SCOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) if you want to learn.