# Triple Join in SQL with unique output

Tags: sql

I currently have 3 tables (diagnosis, encounters, and encounter diagnosis). [1 is the link to see the table outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aa8V.png)

I currently wrote a code that gives me everything I want, but I am looking for the first time a diagnosis occurred.  [code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ9xZ.png)

Here is the code.  Can anyone tell me how to get rid of duplicates?

```
SELECT a.code, a.title, c.start_dts    
FROM edw_emr_ods.diagnoses AS a    
JOIN edw_emr_ods.encounter_diagnoses as b on a.diagnosis_id=b.diagnosis_id    
JOIN edw_emr_ods.encounters as c on b.encounter_id=c.encounter_id    
ORDER BY a.title ASC;
```

I tried grouping, but I get an error that `a.code` is not listed in the GROUP.
Sorry I'm new to SQL and trying to pass a test and this is a practice problem

Comment: How would you do it if you didn't have a triple join? Point is, you should reduce your problem before posting here, so you have a minimal example that anyone can just use in order to reproduce the problem themselves.

Comment: They don't look like duplicates to me. They have different dates.

Comment: Learn more about joins here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for the first time a diagnosis occurred.

In this case, I think if you do a `group by` and using `MIN` for the date would help, more or less like that

```
SELECT a.code, a.title, MIN(c.start_dts)
FROM edw_emr_ods.diagnoses AS a
JOIN edw_emr_ods.encounter_diagnoses AS b on a.diagnosis_id=b.diagnosis_id
JOIN edw_emr_ods.encounters AS c on b.encounter_id=c.encounter_id
GROUP BY a.code, a.title
ORDER BY a.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your group by should be this:

```
GROUP BY a.code, a.title, c.start_dts
```

That's if you want separate rows with separate c.start_dts.  If you just want the first start_dts, your code would be:

```
SELECT a.code, a.title, MIN(c.start_dts)

FROM edw_emr_ods.diagnoses AS a

JOIN edw_emr_ods.encounter_diagnoses as b on a.diagnosis_id=b.diagnosis_id

JOIN edw_emr_ods.encounters as c on b.encounter_id=c.encounter_id

GROUP BY a.code, a.title

ORDER BY a.title ASC;
```