# sql - subtract values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

im new to sql. i tried to make simple subtraction of two columns from two tables.
for example:

```
Table1 = id, amount, value

Table2 = id, amount
```

how can i subtract amount 1 with amount 2 without adding total amount in each column. because i want to view it in row..
this is what i have tried so far but still fail..

```
"SELECT ( SELECT amount FROM table1 ) - ( SELECT amount FROM table2 ) AS difference"
```

btw i want to ask, is there any way that sql can auto generate table or extra column to view the difference / result of subtraction?

thank you

Comment: use a join and then substraction

Comment: `select t1.amount - t2.amount from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly perform operations on multiple columns and show that result in a new column which you can name using `as` clause. You can perform join to do operation between two columns of different tables in a similar fashion. To answer your question, following is the SQL query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.amount-b.amount as Difference FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id=b.id
```

Comment: Table aliases like A, B, C etc don't make much sense. Chose aliases that make you understand which table it is. I'd go with t1 and t2 for table1 and table2. (Silly table names, I know.)

Comment: @jarlh LoL.. Ofcourse. It was just an example. We should name them which makes sense.

Comment: btw.. i have extra question.. Can we set the " as Difference" turn into one of the new column or new table in database??

Comment: @awang to set that as a new column or new table, you have to create a new table or alter some table. In my opinion, you can create a view for that query which will return you the same result as querying a table. To create the view, prepend this before the select statement : "CREATE VIEW differrence_view_name as ". Hope this helps

Comment: once you create the view, you can just query the view like :
select * from difference_view_name

it will give you the result

Answer (score 0):

To subtract the column values from two different tables first `JOIN` the tables and then use the `SUBTRACT` operator to get the difference

```
SELECT t1.id, (t1.amount-t2.amount) as "DIFFERENCE" FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

for more info on `JOINS` 
[SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: Table aliases like A, B, C etc don't make much sense. Chose aliases that make you understand which table it is. I'd go with t1 and t2 for table1 and table2. (Silly table names, I know.)

Comment: btw.. i have extra question.. Can we set the " as Difference" turn into one of the new column or new table in database??