# I get duplicate data in inner join with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: Customers, Receipts, Salary

```
Customers
 Id    Name    
  1    john

Receipts
Id    Amount 
1      500
2      250
3      600
4      700

Salary
Id   Amount 
1    300
2    300
3    680
```

Id like to find sum of salary and receipts related to john.
I thought it's simple sql statement like:

```
select  cus.Name, sum(sal.Amount) as Salary, sum(re.Amount) as Recieved 
from Customers as cus inner join Salaries as sal on cus.Id = sal.Id
inner join Receipts as re on cus.Id = re.Id
where cus.Id= 1
Group by cus.Name
```

but I found the result so bigger

```
Name    Salary   Recieved
john    6150      4320
```

When I write the query without sum:

```
select  cus.Name, sal.Amount as Salary, re.Amount as Recieved 
    from Customers as cus inner join Salaries as sal on cus.Id = sal.Id
    inner join Receipts as re on cus.Id = re.Id
    where cus.Id= 1
```

I get these duplicate records

```
    john    500 100
    john    500 300
    john    500 680
    john    250 100
    john    250 300
    john    250 680
    john    600 100
    john    600 300
    john    600 680
    john    700 100
    john    700 300
    john    700 680
```

why the inner join behavior like this? I expect to get the records one time but it repeated 4 times!
Did I have to try sub-select queries?

Comment: where is `CustomerOrSupplier` column  in `Customers` table? And Add your expected output

Comment: Umm, no, you didn't get the results you say you got with the sample data you have posted.   Please post a script that reproduces the results you are getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: I make miss typing. CustomerOrSupplier is wrong. I edit the srcript

Comment: The question is still wrong.  You are joining on ID, yet there is only one Receipt with ID=1, and only one Salary, so you would not be getting multiple rows if that were true.

Comment: Is your sample data correct?

Comment: The sample data must be wrong or incomplete because there is no value 100 in any of your amount columns, or any other column.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks right.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b5157/1

There's a fiddle with your approximate query and it works as expected. So as the person before said, since you have CustomerOrSupplier, you might be joining to the wrong table

Answer (score 0):

```
select  cus.Name, 
        sum(sal.Amount) as Salary, 
        sum(re.Amount) as Recieved 
from Customers as cus 
inner join Salary as sal 
on cus.Id = sal.Id
inner join 
Receipts as re 
on cus.Id = re.Id
Group by cus.Name;
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/956fb/10

Answer (score 0):

I see that the issue happens to be one of the **tables names**.

Change the following:

```
from Customers as cus inner 
join Salaries as sal 
on cus.Id = sal.Id
```

to:

```
from Customers as cus inner 
join Salary as sal 
on cus.Id = sal.Id
```