# Detailed explanation about SQL JOINS

Tags: sql, join

Is there any source that explains **SQL JOINS** in detail with examples?

Comment: Most probably. Try google.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good place for you. with examples and diagrams.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Comment: The website also has many sections that I will benefit from, like programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Why search elsewhere when you have the answer in StackOverflow itself.

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: Thank you, I tried searching earlier but could not find the answer.