# mysql database problem in fetching data from 4 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

[tbl_users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOxtt.png)

[tbl_questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw4YB.png)

[tbl_answares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGpyF.png)

[tbl_questions_votes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEunx.png)

```
SELECT
    `tbl_users`.`email`,
    `tbl_questions`.`q_id`,
    `tbl_questions`.`question`,
    `tbl_questions`.`tags`,
    `tbl_questions`.`posted_at`,
    SUM(tbl_questions_votes.upvote) AS upvotes,
    SUM(tbl_questions_votes.downvote) AS downvotes
FROM 
    `tbl_users`
INNER JOIN 
    `tbl_answares` 
ON 
    `tbl_answares`.`user_id` = `tbl_users`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN 
    `tbl_questions` 
ON 
    `tbl_questions`.`q_id` = `tbl_answares`.`q_id`
LEFT JOIN 
    `tbl_questions_votes` 
ON 
    `tbl_questions`.`q_id` = `tbl_questions_votes`.`q_id`
WHERE
    `tbl_users`.`user_status` = 1 AND `tbl_answares`.`user_id` = '6'
GROUP BY
    `tbl_questions`.`q_id`
ORDER BY
    `tbl_questions`.`posted_at`
DESC
```

Above query is returning email of user that answered the question (another columns are right output) but, i want the email of the user that asked the question.

**output:** [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uDAw.png)

**Expected Output**

```
`tbl_users`.`email`, // email of user that asked the question
`tbl_questions`.`q_id`,
`tbl_questions`.`question`,
`tbl_questions`.`tags`,
`tbl_questions`.`posted_at`,
SUM(tbl_questions_votes.upvote) AS upvotes,
SUM(tbl_questions_votes.downvote) AS downvotes
```

Comment: Let us see some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `INNER JOIN` on `tbl_questions_votes` to a `LEFT JOIN`, since I'd assume it doesn't matter if a question has votes or not.

Secondly, you're joining the table `answares` and `questions` both on `user_id`. I don't think this makes too much sense, it seems to me that you're fetching `users` with the `questions` that they did and all the `answares` they submmited; while the expected output is the `questions` that this user has `answared`!

So, I think it would make more sense if you joined like this:

```
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_answares 
ON 
    tbl_answares.user_id = tbl_users.user_id
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_questions 
ON 
    tbl_questions.q_id = tbl_answares.q_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_questions_votes 
ON 
    tbl_questions.q_id = tbl_questions_votes.q_id
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_users usrs2 
ON 
    tbl_questions.user_id = usrs2.user_id
```

This joins a `user` with **his** `answares` along with the `answares` particular `questions` and the `votes` casted for those `questions`, without excluding `questions` that has no `votes`; and finnally joining with the `users` that made each `question` you are retrieving.

If you have any doubts around joining tables in SQL, I recommend [this great SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: i get the email of the user that answered the question but i want the email of the user that asked the question. after implementing your solution i got result perfectly but only the email column is not right(wrong email).

Comment: On your select you have `tbl_users`.`email`. This selects the user that answered the question because there is an `INNER JOIN` on `answares`, and a `WHERE` statement restricting only certain `user_id` on `answares`. This is all correct! The thing is, if you want to select the `email` of the user that asked the question, you have to fetch it from `tbl_questions.user_id`

Comment: it is possible with nested query ?

Comment: It is possible with a subquery indeed. There are many ways you can retrieve this data, but, the **best** way depends on a lot of things that are specific of your application.

Comment: @sandip came back with a tip: Try adding a self join at the end like this -> `LEFT JOIN tbl_users usrs2 ON tbl_questions.user_id = usrs2.user_id`, and then use `usrs2.email` to fetch the email of the user that asked the question. I didn't test this, not sure if it'll work. Might update answer later with this

Comment: thanks Lucas  Wieloch. Your suggestions are work perfectly.