# Select columns from two tables

Tags: sql

Table A: 
AID      type  
10           a  
10              b  
10              c  
11              abc  
11              bcd  
11              cde

Table B  
BID         Name 
10             ab   
10             bc   
10             cd   
11             abcd  
11             bcde  
11             cdef

Result Should be

AID     type       Name 
10              a                ab    
10              b                bc    
10              c                cd    
11              abc              abcd  
11              bcd              bcde   
11              cde              cdef

could you please help me on this for the SQL query

Comment: Hint: join table A and B using ID column and select the required columns

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins/20298671

Comment: No this will not work. If I use join by ID, I will get 18 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to align two tables, but do not have a key.  You can generate a key using `row_number()` and then match.  Just note that you cannot control *which* values from the two tables match, unless you have another column that specifies the ordering.

So:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by aid order by name) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by bid order by name) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.aid = b.bid and a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Comment: remove `partition by aid` & `partition by bid` from the statement

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this join:

```
select a.aid, a.type, b.name
from TableA a inner join TableB b
on b.bid = a.aid and b.name like concat(a.type, '%')
```

this will give you the 6 rows from `TableA` with `name` from `TableB` as 3d column.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/duBMHtYsftTMtgacSFx1H1/0).
Results:

```
| aid | type | name |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 10  | a    | ab   |
| 10  | b    | bc   |
| 10  | c    | cd   |
| 11  | abc  | abcd |
| 11  | bcd  | bcde |
| 11  | cde  | cdef |
```