# Access data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to access a piece of data from another table. I'm trying to reach GameName field but I don't really know how to do this.

I tried to create another procedure but this didn't really work out.

PlayerGamesList.sql

```
...
SELECT
    t.PlayerId,
    t.GameId,
    t.TeamId,
    t.Position
FROM
    [PlayerOnGame] t
```

PlayerOnGame.sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PlayerOnGame]
(
    [PlayerOnGameId] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [PlayerId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [GameId] BIGINT NULL,
    [TeamId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [Position] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
...
)
```

and `Game.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Game] 
(
    [GameId] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [Name]   NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

How can I access this specific GameId? I mean how can I do something like GameId.Name?

Comment: If you are asking how to fetch rows from both tables based on GameId then you need an `INNER JOIN` : https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-inner-join.php

Comment: Joint the tables you want the data from

Comment: read this to look on joins in sql server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in, you don't want to see the game id, you want to see the name:

```
SELECT
    t.PlayerId,
    g.Name,
    t.TeamId,
    t.Position
FROM
    [PlayerOnGame] t
    INNER JOIN [Game] g ON g.GameId = t.GameId
```

Note though that you've said that `[PlayerOnGame].[Name]` is allowed to be null, which means you have the potential that some `[PlayerOnGame]` records don't have a `[GameId]` set. INNER JOIN will cause these rows to disappear from the results. If you want to keep them and show a null for the name, make it a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!