# SQL Join multiple values to multiple values

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables which I want to join. I have tried `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `INNER` joins on Table but no success.

Table1

```
Name1  Name2
------------
A      1
B      2
C      3
D      1
```

Table2

```
Name2  Name3
------------
1      x
1      y
2      x
3      x
3      y
3      z
4      y
```

The result for what I am looking for is:

ResultTable

```
Name1 Name2 Name3
------------------
A     1     x
A     1     y
B     2     x
C     3     x
C     3     y
C     3     z
D     1     x 
D     1     y
```

Comment: Please explain what you try to do

Comment: Please left your SQL code to help people know  what's your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using [SQL Server Join Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17946222/10532500).

```
Select Table1.Name1, Table1.Name2, Table2.Name3
from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.Name2 = Table2.Name2
```

Here is the implementation.

```
create table Table1 (Name1 varchar(5), Name2 int)
Insert into Table1 Values ('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3), ('D',1)

create table Table2 (Name2 int, Name3 varchar(5))
Insert into Table2 
         Values (1, 'x'), (1, 'y'), (2, 'x'), (3, 'x'), (3, 'y'), (3, 'z'), (4, 'y')

Select Table1.Name1, Table1.Name2, Table2.Name3
from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.Name2 = Table2.Name2
```

The output is as shown below.

```
Name1   Name2   Name3
----------------------
A       1       x
A       1       y
B       2       x
C       3       x
C       3       y
C       3       z
D       1       x
D       1       y
```

[**Online Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b13c942d18438d320f6a751cddb4b99)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i have edited the post i made a mistake on question. The problem is with the Table2 D value, this query returs D only once without right table value.

Comment: Please check the output it is as your expected output. Request you to accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: @SurajKumar answers can be helpful even if they don't completely answer the question, accepting an answer should be reserved for answers that fully answer the question