# HR SCHEMA ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

HR SCHEMA ORACLE

Create Function “GET_EMPLOYEE_SUMMARY” that receives an Employee ID and that returns, through an output parameter, a data structure with the following information:
 - Employee ID
 - First Name
 - Last Name
 - Manager Name
 - Department Name

So, the manager_name is baseade on employee_id..

Query:

```
select  

      e.first_name as first_name,
      e.last_name,
      e.employee_id,
      e.manager_id as Name,
      d.department_name

      from employees e 
      Cross join departments d
```

but i have some mistakes... idk

Comment: `CROSS JOIN`?!?  I'd do a regular `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You need to JOIN employees one more time to get the manager name.

Comment: but when i do a join, it's not complete. because in table employees, i have employee id = 100 and manager id = 101 ex.., and the first_name of 101 is alex and the 100 is joao,
when i return a 100 employee query the name of manager didn't come.. is a number.. i have to relacionate it to a name

Comment: how  i join again ?

Comment: join employees e2 on e.manager_id = e2.employee_id

Comment: @JosèOliviera: to understand the different join types I suggest you read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a self join with the `EMPLOYEE` table again and join with the `DEPARTMENT` table should be inner join.

Something like following is needed:

```
SELECT
    E.FIRST_NAME   AS FIRST_NAME,
    E.LAST_NAME,
    E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    M.FIRST_NAME || M.LAST_NAME   AS MANAGER_NAME, -- Change it according to your requirement
    D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM
    EMPLOYEES E
    JOIN EMPLOYEES M ON E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMPLOYEE_ID
    JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE
    E.EMPLOYEE_ID = 100;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks very much like homework, here is a rough guide and you'll need to fill in the blanks:

The first part of your question is to:

> create Function `GET_EMPLOYEE_SUMMARY`

so you should not be starting by writing a SQL query but should be writing a PL/SQL statement:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GET_EMPLOYEE_SUMMARY ...
```

You can look up the complete syntax in [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-FUNCTION-statement.html#GUID-B71BC5BD-B87C-4054-AAA5-213E856651F2).

> that receives an Employee ID

So one of the arguments to the function should be something like:

```sql
i_employee_id IN EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE
```

> and that returns, through an output parameter, a data structure with the following information ...

So your return type should be a [custom type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TYPE-statement.html#GUID-389D603D-FBD0-452A-8414-240BBBC57034) created with a statement like:

```sql
CREATE TYPE <your_type_name> AS OBJECT(
  <list_of_properties _and_data_types>
)
```

and then you can use that return type in your function declaration.

When it comes to write the PL/SQL block for your function then you can include your query which should look something like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION <your_function_signature>
IS
  <declare your local variables>
BEGIN
  SELECT E.FIRST_NAME,
         E.LAST_NAME,
         M.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || M.LAST_NAME
         D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
  INTO   <your_first_name_variable>,
         <your_last_name_variable>,
         <your_manager_name_variable>,
         <your_department_name_variable>
  FROM   EMPLOYEES E
         LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES M
         ON ( E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMPLOYEE_ID )
         INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D
         ON ( D.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID )
  WHERE  E.EMPLOYEE_ID = i_employee_id;

  <do stuff>

  RETURN <your_custom_type>
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    <handle the exception>
END;
/
```

Comment: thx bro, in sql (querys) i understand a little, but pl-sql i have very dificults.

Comment: it's not my homework.. it's just a tutorial to see if i go with this view ( developer) or not in company... i like development, but pl-sql it's so dificult