# How can I query the list of IDs with conditions on couple of fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables:

Table A

```
ID Code1 Code2
--------------
1 2000  1
2 3000  2
3 1000  3
4 2100  1
5 3500  5
```

Table B

```
Code1 Code2
-----------
2100  7
2100  1
3000  2
1000  4
```

I need to get the IDs from Table A that have values of Code1, Code2 equal to 
values of Code1,Code2 from table B?

I need to get the following result.

```
ID 
--
2
4
```

Comment: Have you tried anything (like an `inner join`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this using `exists` as shown below.

```
create table TableA (id int, Code1 int, Code2 int)
insert into TableA values
(1, 2000,  1),
(2, 3000,  2),
(3, 1000,  3),
(4, 2100,  1),
(5, 3500,  5)

Create table TableB(Code1 int, Code2 int)
insert into TableB Values
(2100,  7),
(2100,  1),
(3000,  2),
(1000,  4)

Select 
   TableA.Id
from TableA
where exists (Select 1 from TableB where tableA.Code1 = tableB.Code1
and TableA.Code2 = tableB.Code2)
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=76d9b91bfb7f77ee10b78614a0b3cc80).
It looks as shown in the below image.

[image]

Another way is to use the [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)
.

Comment: @SmartDev . . . I prefer `exists` because it is guaranteed not to generate duplicate rows in the first table.

Comment: . . .  You should add table alias to make it clear for correlation.

Answer (score 4):

Can you not simply do an `INNER JOIN` on the two values you need to compare?

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM tablea t1
INNER JOIN tableb t2 ON t1.Code1 = t2.Code1 AND t1.Code2 = t2.Code2
```