# How to link from Table1 to Table2 in SQL where the value returned from Table2 is based on an index value from Table1?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am fairly new to SQL and have been able to run queries from a single table in a single DB.  But now I need to access the codes and their true values from another table in another DB and I'm not sure how to do that. It probably involves the JOIN command but I haven't been able to make it work.

Here is a summary of my data:

DB1.Table1

```
Procedure Code  Procedure Description   PIC Code ID
----------------------------------------------------
10005001        INJECTION 20ML          707
10005002        INJECTION 30ML          707
20008850        BLOOD CBC               254
```

DB2.Table2

```
PIC Code ID PIC Code    PIC Code Description
---------------------------------------------
707         250         PHARMACY
707         250         PHARMACY
254         300         LABORATORY
```

My query starts in DB1.Table1 but I am to be able to link to DB2.Table2 and return the value in column PIC Code instead of PIC Code ID.

So the output would be similar to:

```
Procedure Code  Procedure Description   PIC Code
-------------------------------------------------
10005001        INJECTION 20ML          250
10005002        INJECTION 30ML          250
20008850        BLOOD CBC               300
```

The PIC Code ID is an index that is used at run time and not the true code that the end user would recognize.

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this on S.O. and plenty of answers with examples. I suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21085546/3950497. And next time you should provide an example of what you have tried so far, so people can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a simple `join`:

```
select t1.procedure_code, t1.procedure_description, t2.pic_code
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
    on t2.pic_code_id = t1.pic_code_id
```

Your data is showing duplicates in `table2`, but I am unsure that's what you really have, because your question does not mention that - so the query does not handles that. But if you really need to:

```
select t1.procedure_code, t1.procedure_description, t2.pic_code
from table1 t1
inner join (select distinct pic_code_id, pic_code from table2) t2 
    on t2.pic_code_id = t1.pic_code_id
```

Comment: the data in OP's question has duplicates and you are admittedly posting an answer that does not work?

Comment: @BryanDellinger: I don't see your point. The answer explains the rationale for the first query, and addresses the duplicates in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove duplicates from table2, then you can join result with table1.

```
select
     t1.Procedure_Code
    ,t1.Procedure
    ,t1.Description
    ,t2.PIC_Code
from DB1.Table1 t1
left join (
    select
        PIC_Code_ID
        ,max(PIC_Code) as PIC_Code
    from DB2.Table2
    group by
        PIC_Code_ID
    ) t2 on t1.PIC_Code_ID = t2.PIC_Code_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a correlated subquery.

```
select Procedure_Code, Procedure_Description,
(select Max(PIC_Code)
 from Table2 b
 where a.PIC_Code_ID = b.PIC_Code_ID
) as PIC_Code
from Table1 a
```

run fiddle here  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sUAjQdMVyyhqwF6okdaiVQ/0