# Joining with a virtual predicate

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need to formulate a query that gets me the row in one table based on the ID from a result of an average function in a grouped query in another table.

I have two tables, one for book details and one with their ratings ('books' and 'reviews'). Stripped down to the essentials:

```
+--------+--------+
| bookid |  name  |
+--------+--------+
|    4   |  LOTR  |
|    5   |  Bible |
+--------+--------+

+--------+--------+
| bookid | rating |
+--------+--------+
|    4   |   2    |
|    5   |   2    |
|    4   |   3    |
|    5   |   4    |
+--------+--------+
```

With a query

```
SELECT bookid
     , AVG(rating) AS avg_rating 
  FROM reviews 
 GROUP 
    BY book_id 
 ORDER 
    BY avg_rating DESC
```

I get the best average score. In this case, bookid 4 has a score of 2.5 and bookid 5 has a score of 3; the query returns one row: the bookid `5` as the first part, and the score `3` as the second.

By keeping the virtual column result in a variable and issuing a new query, I can get hold of the book name:

```
$topbook = $result['bookid'];
$topscore = $result['avg_rating']; 
$getname = "
SELECT name 
  FROM books 
 WHERE bookid = $topbook
";
[...]
print "Best book: $getname with a score of $topscore"; // Bible with a score of 3
```

This works. But I am curious as to how I can combine this **into one query**, joining the tables based on a condition that is the result of a virtual calculation involving grouping, as shown above? All while also keeping the second value in the first query (avg_rating) for printing?

Any pointers are much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Within your SELECT can you not just do `SELECT bookid, name, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating ...`

Comment: @hppycoder thanks for the quick reaction! But 'name' is a column in the books table while 'AVG(rating)' is in the reviews table; hence the "SELECT ... FROM reviews" in my first query. Could you please clarify with the complete query? as I am unsure how you would solve the FROM part. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i've submitted an answer below. It will be using LEFT JOIN which has a good description here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins

Comment: Find out how to use a "subquery" including a "scalar subquery".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification in the comments. We'll use LEFT JOIN here to combine the two tables together with the common key being `bookid` in reviews linking to `bookid` in the books table.

```
SELECT r.bookid, AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating, b.name
FROM reviews r
LEFT JOIN books b ON b.bookid = r.bookid
GROUP BY r.bookid 
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
```

Comment: This is PERFECT. Thanks so much, I learned something here!

Comment: Also, thanks to @Strawberry for silently reformatting (clarifying and standardizing) my original code.