# How can I 'weight' a fulltext search on one table (podcasts_episodes) by a field (weight) in another table (podcasts) that coresponds to the id?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I 'weight' a fulltext search on one table (podcasts_episodes) by a field (weight) in another table (podcasts) that coresponds to the id?

An example of both tables:

```
mysql> describe podcasts;
+--------------+--------------+
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+
| id           | int(12)      |
| name         | varchar(200) |
| weight       | float        |
+--------------+--------------+

mysql> describe podcasts_episodes;
+-------------+--------------+
| Field       | Type         |
+-------------+--------------+
| id          | int(12)      |
| name        | varchar(200) |
| link        | varchar(255) |
| description | text         |
| podcast     | int(12)      |
| weight      | float        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Rather than having to set a weight for each episode, it would be far simpler to use a common one in the podcasts table.

In the podcasts_episodes table, the field 'podcast' matches the id in the podcsts table for the podcast that episode belongs to.

The sql query I have been using, which needs updated as described is:

```
SELECT 
    *, MATCH(name,description) AGAINST('industrial') AS relevance
FROM 
    podcasts_episodes
WHERE 
    MATCH(name,description) AGAINST('industrial') 
ORDER BY 
    weight DESC, relevance DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The expected outcome should be that only relevant results show up, but results weighted higher should get a boost above lower weighted results.

Comment: Could you please add the expected outcome?

Comment: @JonasMetzler done. not sure why I didn't specify that at first, thanks.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but it sounds like you do not know about [`join`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17946221). If you don't: props to you for the correct gut feeling that the podcast weight makes more sense the podcast table, and not duplicated into the episode table.

Comment: @Solarflare would you happen to have an example for the above need?