# Difference between inner join query with a inner join..on and where clause query?

Tags: mysql, join

Lets say I have two tables student, records with the schema being

> Students (id, name)
>   Records    (rid,sid,subject,marks)

and I want to print (name, subject,marks).

So I can write the inner join in two ways

```
> select a.name,b.subject,b.marks from students a, records b where a.id = b.sid;
or
> select a.name,b.subject,b.marks from students a inner join records b on a.id = b.sid;
```

Obviously, they both are returning the same results and taking same amount of time. So I am not sure if internally they both are same or if there is any scenario where either of those is preferable over the other?

Comment: There is no difference. 

See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join

Comment: possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are wrong. I assume this is a mistake, and the first `where` is supposed to be a `from`:

```
> select a.name,b.subject,b.marks from students a, records b where a.id = b.sid;
or
> select a.name,b.subject,b.marks from students a inner join records b on a.id = b.sid;
```

If we disregard this mistake and examine the queries above - these two statements are functionally equivalent, but implicit joins (the first form) has been deprecated for a long while. Hence, it's suggested to use explicit joins (the second form). An added bonus to them is the increased readability of the code - the join conditions are neatly arranged with the `join`s, and the `where` clause is left free to handle just the logic of the query.

Comment: I obviously wrote dummy queries for the purpose of this question. But how are queries wrong?

Comment: They have an additional `where` clause instead of a `from` clause, as I stated - check out the corrected queries in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same and are executed the same way. Do a

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...
```

on your queries and enable the warnings. Then mySQL will give you a warning containing the query after the optimizer had it. There should be the same warning for both queries.