# Why this subquery is 10x faster than inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables ecdict and favourite and one view which just inner join two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE ecdict('_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'word' VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE, 'meaning' VARCHAR, 'phonetic_string' VARCHAR, 'example' VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE favourite('_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'word' VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE);

CREATE VIEW favourite_word as select ecdict.* from ecdict INNER JOIN favourite ON ecdict.word = favourite.word;
```

**Here is the execution time of result:**
Time: 0.010

```
select ecdict.* from ecdict where word in (select word from favourite);
```

Time: 0.226

```
select * from favourite_word;
```

Why they differ so much? It if is related to query plan, why sqlite chooses a slower one? How can I guide sqlite to choose the faster one? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the query plan to see what is really happening.  The following is (informed) speculation.

When you have an inner join with two sets of indexes, you basically have two possible query plans:

1. Scan the `edict` table and look up words in the `favourites` using the index on `favourite.word`.
2. Scan the `favourite` table and look up words in `edicts` using the index on `edicts(word)`.  Then look up the record in `edit` when there is a match.

(A unique contraint creates an index.)

All these being equal -- that is, with no information about table sizes -- the first approach would be preferred in this case.  Why?  Because there is no additional step to look up the additional columns.

When you phrase the query using `in`, I think that SQLite will always use the first approach.  In this case, I am guessing that the `favourite` table is much smaller than the `edict` table, so the second approach is actually better.  When you write the query as a `join`, both possibilities are considered and the better one is chosen.

Comment: Yes, favourite is much smaller. But won't sqlite choose the faster one for me?

Comment: @Bear . . . It will for the explicit `join`.  But the `in` would focus on the index on `favourite`.  It *could* consider the other direction, but that is really a very special case because the two columns are both declared unique.

Comment: Thanks so much.  But if explict join will find a better one for me,  it should choose the second approach

Comment: @Bear . . . The explicit `join` does appear to choose the second option.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I really want to know about this more. For example, why it would choose the slower one and how can I make sqlite choose the faster one. I have update the question for this.

Comment: @Bear . . . Use the `join` syntax.  It has more optimization methods.

Comment: from my understanding, join is basically the same as inner join.  reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join

Comment: @Bear . . . A `join` *is* the same.  The issue is the `in`, not the `join` -- the `join` is producing the better plan.  SQLite apparently doesn't look at every conceivable optimization path that the `join` does.  And, this is a very special case because of the unique indexes in both tables.