# Create view problems

Tags: sql

I need to create a view that contains the `id` and names of actors that are in a drama film that released in 2010.

I wrote this:

```
CREATE VIEW DRAMA_ACTORS 
AS 
    SELECT 
        ACTOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
    FROM 
        ACTOR, FILM_ACTOR, FILM, FILM_CATEGORY, CATEGORY
    WHERE 
        ACOTR.ACTOR_ID = FILM_ACTOR.ACTOR_ID
        AND FILM_ACTOR.FILM_ID = FILM.FILM_ID
        AND FILM.FILM_ID = FILM_CATEGORY.FILM_ID
        AND FILM_CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID = CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID
        AND CATEGORY.NAME = 'Drama'
        AND FILM.RELEASE_YEAR = '2010';
```

The schema is like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Do SELECT DISTINCT to avoid duplicates (if an actor has been in several movies that year.) Do you store years as text?!? Don't do that, use integer!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT a.ACTOR_ID, a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME
FROM FILM AS f
JOIN FILM_ACTOR AS fa ON fa.FILM_ID = f.FILM_ID
JOIN ACOTR AS a ON a.ACTOR_ID = fa.ACTOR_ID
JOIN FILM_CATEGORY AS fc ON fc.FILM_ID = f.FILM_ID
JOIN CATEGORY AS c ON c.CATEGORY_ID = fc.CATEGORY_ID
WHERE c.NAME = 'Drama' AND f.RELEASE_YEAR = '2010'
```

If you got duplicate results, use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in your query.

Comment: what's the difference between inner join and join? thanks

Comment: The top answer of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join) should be better than my explanation:)

Comment: so in this case, can i use join as well?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions?!?

Comment: JOIN is just short form for INNER JOIN. (And LEFT JOIN is short form for LEFT OUTER JOIN.)

Comment: @jarlh I intended it to just avoid duplication. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's better (In my opinion) to avoid creating duplicates in the first place, rather than to eliminate them afterwards.

If we want to identify actors who've been in a drama in 2010, it shouldn't matter if they've been in multiple films - we just want to assert that at least one such film exists:

```
SELECT 
    ACTOR_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM 
    ACTOR a
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM FILM_ACTOR fa
               INNER JOIN
            FILM f
               ON fa.FILM_ID = f.FILM_ID
               INNER JOIN
            FILM_CATEGORY fc
               ON
                  fc.FILE_ID = f.FILM_ID
               INNER JOIN
            CATEGORY c
               ON
                  fc.CATEGORY_ID = c.CATEGORY_ID
    WHERE
        a.ACTOR_ID = fa.ACTOR_ID
    AND c.NAME = 'Drama'
    AND f.RELEASE_YEAR = '2010'
);
```