# Return NULL if no rows are found SQL

Tags: sql

newbie to SQL, please help.  I only know basic syntax but know I can't accomplish what I want to with it:

Have two tables:

`user_table`:

```
id   name
1   george
2   harry
3   ralph
```

`updown_table`:

```
id  updown
1   up
3   down
```

My query:

```
select  
    u.id,
    u.name,
    up.updown
from    
    user_table u, updown_table up
where   
    u.id = up.id;
```

I'd like it to return id's 1, 2, 3 and put a NULL value in for 2.  But obviously as the entry doesn't exist in updown, it will only return 1 and 3.

Any help, please?

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). And don't use this old implicit join syntax any more.

Comment: First thing to learn is explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of that old, comma separated, implicit join...

Comment: @jarlh: I like how you think :)

Comment: @juergend, when @namja knows the proper `INNER JOIN` syntax, it's so easy to take the next step to `LEFT JOIN`!

Comment: @juergend Thank you!  LEFT JOIN is definitely getting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```
Select  
    u.id,
    u.name,
    up.updown
From    
    user_table u left join updown_table up ON u.id=up.id;
```

Also as a reference for you: [Difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join)

Comment: thank you!  This is definitely putting me on the right direction.

Comment: @namja you can accept my reply as your final answer to close this question. thanks!