# How to do the substraction from the same table based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sample Table Data

```
Declare @t table (PolicyNumber varchar(10),Val decimal(18,2),Fund varchar(5),Tenure varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t(PolicyNumber,Val,Fund,Tenure)VALUES 
('ASWPP',10.2,'T001','Secure'),
('ASWPP',5.0,'T002','Secure'),
('ASWPP',5.0,'T003','Secure'),
('XPPW',15.2,'T001','Growth'),
('XPPW',10.2,'T002','Growth'),
('XPPW',10.2,'T003','Growth'),
('XXXX',20.2,'T001','Secure'),
('XXXX',10.2,'T002','Secure'),
('XXXX',10.2,'T003','Secure')
```

How to do the Subtraction from same table basing on Policy number.

I need to subtract the Fund = 002 from 
the other funds (T001,T003)

I need to get the output like below :

```
 PolicyNumber   Val        Fund           Tenure
 ASWPP          5.2        T001            Secure     
 ASWPP          0.0        T003            Secure     
 XPPW           5.2        T001            Growth     
 XPPW           0.2        T003            Growth     
 XXXX           10.2       T001           Secure     
 XXXX           0.0        T003            Secure
```

Suggest me the best way

Comment: where you are not clear ? In T001,T003 need to get subtracted from T002.

Comment: Should the 5th row (`XXXX, 10.2, T001, Secure`) not have a value of 10 for `Val` (20.2 - 10.2) rather than 10.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the table to itself, with one instance excluding the `T002` records, and one instance only containing them:

```
SELECT  t.PolicyNumber,
        Val = t.Val - ISNULL(t2.Val, 0),
        t.Fund,
        t.Tenure
FROM    @T AS t
        LEFT JOIN @T AS t2
            ON t2.PolicyNumber = t.PolicyNumber
            AND t2.Fund = 'T002'
WHERE   t.Fund <> 'T002';
```

If the type of PolicyNumber and Fund is not unique, then you may need a subquery for it to avoid duplication:

```
SELECT  t.PolicyNumber,
        Val = t.Val - ISNULL(t2.Val, 0),
        t.Fund,
        t.Tenure
FROM    @T AS t
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  PolicyNumber, Val = SUM(Val)
            FROM    @T 
            WHERE   Fund = 'T002'
            GROUP BY PolicyNumber
        ) AS t2
            ON t2.PolicyNumber = t.PolicyNumber
WHERE   T.Fund <> 'T002';
```

Comment: I think, expected output is not correct. `XXXX           10.2       T001           Secure `

Answer (score 1):

Join that table on itself like this:

```
SELECT t1.PolicyNumber, t2.val - t1.val AS val, t2.Fund, t2.Tenure
  FROM t t1
  JOIN t t2
    ON t1.PolicyNumber = t2.PolicyNumber AND t2.FUND != 'T002'
 WHERE t1.FUND = 'T002';
```

Comment: Inner join, right. INNER here is just a syntactic sugar, can be dropped out. Right aligned by pressing spacebars, just a little usefull habit.

Comment: Maybe it's personal opinion, 1) I prefer `INNER JOIN` as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join; 2) Right aligned code make troubles; You have to be thinking what is the longest keyword in this statement while typing. If you add a HAVING later, will you update all lines above?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way.

```
Select a.PolicyNumber,
a.Val - t2.Val as NewVal,
a.Fund, a.Tenure
from @t a
join
(
    Select * from @t
    Where Fund = 'T002'
) t2
ON a.PolicyNumber = t2.PolicyNumber
Where a.Fund <> 'T002'
```